# Is there a way to programmatically add text to a System.Drawing.Image?

Tags: c#, gdi+

I have a  System.Drawing.Image that I display with System.Drawing.Graphics DrawImage function.  The image is a police car, and I would like to draw a unit number on top of the police car.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`DrawString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring.aspx) method to write text out onto an image.

```
// Create string to draw.
String drawString = "Sample Text";

// Create font and brush.
Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 16);
SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

// Create point for upper-left corner of drawing.
PointF drawPoint = new PointF(150.0F, 150.0F);

// Draw string to screen.
e.Graphics.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, drawPoint);
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear if you are trying to add the text to the image or just display text on the image:

To the image:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(yourImage))
{
  g.DrawString(...);
}
```

or On the image:

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(...);
e.Graphics.DrawString(...);
```