# Modify / Update a JPEG image programmatically to add a text

Tags: c#, image-processing, jpeg, image-editing

I was wondering if there is an image library in .NET which would allow me to open a JPEG image on the fly and add a text field (for ex: Software version)
Basically I should be able to send the software version to this library. And this image based library should modify/add a text to the image and save it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `System.Drawing` namespace. See this:

[Is there a way to programmatically add text to a System.Drawing.Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149694/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-add-text-to-a-system-drawing-image)

Answer (score 0):

```
Image origImage;
using (Stream s = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
{
    origImage = Image.FromStream(s);
}

using (Image newImage = new Bitmap(origImage))
{
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);
    graphics.DrawString("Software version: " + version, font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);

    newImage.Save(newPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}

origImage.Dispose();
```