# How do I Add a Date as a Watermark in C#?

Tags: c#, watermark

I have an image that I am resizing and then saving it as a stream.  That works well; however, I need to add a Date watermark on it to record when the photo was taken.
Most of the solutions that I encounter are using a file location and do not work with my existing code.  How do I use the graphics method to achieve this with a bit stream image?
here is what I am using now to resize the image:

```
        private byte[] toBytes(Image image)
        {
            Bitmap resized = new Bitmap(image, 1000, 750);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    /////  Maybe I can place the watermark code here and write the date at the bottom, center of the image.

            resized.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            resized.Dispose();
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: ...why not use established image metadata standards?

Comment: My final image is not downloadable and can't be inspected for metadata.  It is generated from a bit stream when needed and not a physical file that resides in a folder on the Server. I would like to visually see the date on the image from its Web page display.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149694/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-add-text-to-a-system-drawing-image

Comment: ^^ which means the date needs to be rendered as image data and then merged with the existing image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated code to handle positioning the text at the bottom right corner

```cs
private byte[] toBytes(Image image)
{
    int targetWidth = 1000; // define target width of the image
    int targetHeight = 750; // define target height of the image
    
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) // create a memory stream to store the image
    using (Bitmap resized = new Bitmap(image, targetWidth, targetHeight)) // create a resized bitmap
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(resized)) // create a graphics object to draw on the resized bitmap
    {
        string text = "01/01/2000"; // define the text string
        
        using (Font font = new Font("Arial", 12)) // define the font and font size
        using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black)) // define the text brush color
        using (StringFormat newStringFormat = new StringFormat()) // create a new string format
        {
            newStringFormat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical; // set the string format flags
            
            SizeF layoutSize = new SizeF(100.0F, 200.0F); // set the maximum layout size
            
            int charactersFitted;
            int linesFilled;
            SizeF stringSize = g.MeasureString(text, font, layoutSize, newStringFormat, out charactersFitted, out linesFilled); // calculate the size of the text
            
            int x = targetWidth - (int)stringSize.Width; // calculate the x position to draw the text
            int y = targetHeight - (int)stringSize.Height; // calculate the y position to draw the text
            
            g.DrawString(text, font, brush, x, y); // draw the text on the image
        }
        
        resized.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg); // save the image to the memory stream
        return ms.ToArray(); // return the memory stream's data array
    }
}
```

You can find more info at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

Comment: [`g.MeasureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) may be helpful in selecting font size and position calculation.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods added your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: You'll also want to ensure `Font font`, `Brush brush`, and `StringFormat newStringFormat` are all in `using()` blocks too.

Comment: @Dai using statements added, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: resized should be `using`'d too. At this point you should use non-block using statements to keep code readable.

Comment: @Ray suggestion added. thanks

Comment: @Ray cleaned the code and used non block using statements.